# Which one of these should be before "for you"

Tags: phrases, expressions, parts-of-speech

I just heard someone say "**fortunately for you**" in the film The Arrow, and I know that "**lucky for you**" is also a synonymous common phrase.

Why is one an adverb and the other an adjective (before **for you**)? and furthermore, I once read that they were some kind of contraction. What is the complete form?

Comment: Hello and welcome. At ELU, we prefer that the questions tell us what you've already looked at, and why you weren't satisfied with them. Please [edit] your question to provide more context for your quotations (at least a complete sentence). Mention and link to the references you've consulted, and what puzzles you about the explanations. Also, I don't understand the significance of the arrow you mention - please explain what it is.

Comment: In the mean time, I'm voting to place your question on hold for lack of research. Please feel free to contact me about reversing that vote after you have edited. You can do this by adding a comment to your own question, and including the 'word' "@Lawrence".

Comment: I believe that the complete form of "lucky for you" is actually "luckily for you," and that "lucky for you" is an easier more informal way of saying it. Therefore, the correct part of speech is _adverb_

Comment: Of course, as Lawrence mentions, context is key.   If it's correct to say "Luckily for you, *X*," then it's probably also correct to say "The fact that *X* is lucky for you."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Luckily for you" means the same thing as "fortunately for you."  This is a fragment, a portion of a longer sentence, such as, "Fortunately for you, I happen to have an extra umbrella in my car."  (Context: a sudden downpour, no parking space close to the theater.)

However, "lucky for you" is a bit different.  A slightly longer, clearer version would be "That was lucky for you!"  Or "How lucky for you!"  Example:

> I have taken my son for a blood test.  His favorite tech is on duty, the one who always gets it on the first try, and distracts him with a joke.  I say, on our way out, "Lucky for you that Miriam was on duty this morning!"

And this means *it was lucky for you* etc.  Here, "lucky" is an adjective modifying "it".

If we wanted to use "luckily" instead, in this same context, it would be

> Luckily for you, Miriam was on duty this morning.

Comment: However, informally "lucky for you" is used improperly in place of "luckily for you," so I wouldn't exactly hint at that you will never see "lucky for you" used as "fortunately for you," because the truth is, you will

Comment: Just a suggestion, but perhaps emphasizing that "luckily for you" is a strict synonym where as "lucky for you" is an informal/improper synonym?

Comment: @DaMaxContent Why do you think there is something improper about *lucky for you*?

Comment: @tchrist guess you misunderstood. Grammatically improper/incorrect to use "Lucky for you" in direct placement of "fortunately for you" or "luckily for you." This is done frequently. That's what I was trying to mention was that you will often see the sentence, "Fortunately/Luckily for you, I happen to have an extra umbrella in my car."  worded "Fortunate/Lucky for you, I happen to have an extra umbrella in my car."

Comment: My point is so that when speaking, OP will not be confused on meaning when exposed to the sentence: "Fortunate/Lucky for you, I happen to have an extra umbrella in my car." That is my point.

Comment: @DaMaxContent What makes you think there's anything grammatically improper/incorrect about “lucky for you” as an exact equivalent to “fortunately for you”? There are simply some ‘X for you’ phrases that use morphologically marked adverbs and some that don't. You hardly ever hear anyone saying “luckily for you”, and I have certainly **never** heard anyone use “fortunate for you” in this way. Just like I've never heard anyone say, “Well for you, I happen…”: it's invariably “good for you”.